# how to ignore some files using sklearn load_files method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My mac os will generate a .DS_Store under my train data set file directory, and load_files will load it and raise exception like

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1116

I want to know that how to filter the .DS_Store file except delete it?

Comment: Can you show us how you iterator over the files?

Comment: @miku: He's presumably relying on [`sklearn.datasets.load_files`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html#sklearn.datasets.load_files) to do the iteration, as his question implies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html#sklearn.datasets.load_files), there doesn't seem to be any way to filter directly in `load_files` (or, rather, you can whitelist categories, but you can't whitelist files within the categories, or blacklist at either level).

You might want to consider filing a feature request to the scikit-learn project. Alternatively, you might consider it a bug that hidden files (as defined appropriately for the platform—but on OS X and other POSIX systems that should include files whose names start with `.`) are loaded, and file a bug report on that.

Meanwhile, there is a `load_content` flag that you can set:

> load_content : boolean, optional (default=True)
>
> Whether to load or not the content of the different files. If true a ‘data’ attribute containing the text information is present in the data structure returned. If not, a filenames attribute gives the path to the files.

Pass `False`, and it will just find the filenames for you, which you can then filter however you want (e.g., `filenames = (filename for filename in ret.filenames if not filename.startswith('.'))`), then load manually.

This seems like the best solution available with the given tools.

On the other hand, given how simple `load_files` actually is—especially if you don't use the extra features like `categories` or `shuffle`—it might be simpler to just not use it, and instead use `os.walk` or just `os.listdir`. In this case, given that the files are exactly 2 levels deep, rather than at an arbitrary depth, the latter is probably simpler:

```
def getfilenames(category):
    return [filename for filename in os.listdir(category)
            if not filename.endswith('.')]
categoryfiles = [getcategory(os.path.join(rootpath, category)
                 for category in os.listdir(rootpath)]
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have change the code of load_file based on your code.

Comment: if we set load_content flag to False then how do we load the files manually ? Can you answer my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788431/scikit-learn-how-to-know-documents-in-the-cluster

Answer (score 0):

A [quick glance at the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/base.py#L164) of [`load_files`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html#sklearn.datasets.load_files) reveals that your only option is to delete the `.DS_Store` files:

```
documents = [join(folder_path, d)
    for d in sorted(listdir(folder_path))]
```

(If you want get serious about the `.DS_Store` *pollution*, here's a serious kernel extension: https://github.com/binaryage/asepsis).

Comment: So passing `load_content=False` and then loading the files iteratively isn't an option?

Comment: @abarnert; I haven't worked with this toolkit, so I can't really answer that.

Comment: Neither have I, but I did read the single short page of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the sklearn [load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html#sklearn.datasets.load_files) to accept additional parameter 'ignore_files' which would accept a list of files to be ignored. You can use this definition of load_files instead of sklearn. It returns the same result as of load_files since I am just filtering the files which needs to be ignored.

usage :

```
load_files(dir_path,ignore_files=".DS_Store")
```

Source on [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeevanel/089e3829408963ccc617)