# scikit-learn how to know documents in the cluster?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, k-means

I am new to both python and scikit-learn so please bear with me.

I took this source code for k means clustering algorithm from [k means clustering.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_downloads/document_clustering.py)

I then modified to run on my local set by using load_file function.

Although the algorithm terminates, but it does not produce any output like which documents are clustered together.

I found that the km object has "km.label" array which lists the centroid id of each document.

It also has the centroid vector with "km.cluster_centers_"

But what document it is ? I have to map it to "dataset" which is a "Bunch" object.

If i print dataset.data[0], i get the data of first file which i think are shuffled. but i just want to know the name.

I am confused with questions like Does the document at dataset.data[0] is clusterd to centoid at km.label[0] ?

**My basic problem is to find which files are clustered together.
How to find that ?**

Comment: Make sure to validate that the results are sensible. K-means will often return results that may be mathematical optimas, but not at all useful for the actual problem at hand!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forget about the `Bunch` object. It's just an implementation detail to load the toy datasets that are bundled with scikit-learn.

In real life, with you real data you just have to call directly:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters).fit(my_document_features)
```

then collect cluster assignments from:

```
km.labels_
```

`my_document_features` is a 2D datastructure: either a numpy array or a scipy.sparse matrix with shape `(n_documents, n_features)`.

`km.labels_` is a 1D numpy array with shape `(n_documents,)`. Hence the first element in `labels_` is the index of the cluster of the document described in the first row of the `my_document_features` feature matrix.

Typically you would build `my_document_features` with a `TfidfVectorizer` object:

```
my_document_features = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(my_text_documents)
```

and `my_text_documents` would a either a list python unicode objects if you read the documents directly (e.g. from a database or rows from a single CSV file or whatever you want) or alternatively:

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer(input='filename')
my_document_features = vec.fit_transform(my_text_files)
```

where `my_text_files` is a python list of the path of your document files on your harddrive (assuming they are encoded using the UTF-8 encoding).

The length of the `my_text_files` or `my_text_documents` lists should be `n_documents` hence the mapping with `km.labels_` is direct.

As scikit-learn is not just for clustering or categorizing documents, we use the name "sample" instead of "document". This is way you will see the we use `n_samples` instead of `n_documents` to document the expected shapes of the arguments and attributes of all the estimator in the library.

Comment: Thank ogrisel. In the sample code dataset.data is your "my_text_files". So how do i find which file is at 0 index ? If it does not store it how can i get the file names while using load_files() function ?

Comment: No: `dataset.data` is a list of in-memory python unicode string with the content of the text files. If you use the `load_files()` utility the `filenames` are stored in the `dataset.filenames` list.

Answer (score 2):

`dataset.filenames` is the key :)

This is how i did it.

load_files declaration is :

```
def load_files(container_path, description=None, categories=None,
           load_content=True, shuffle=True, charset=None,
           charse_error='strict', random_state=0)
```

so do

```
dataset_files = load_files("path_to_directory_containing_category_folders");
```

then when i got the result :

i put them in the clusters which is a dictionary

```
clusters = defaultdict(list)

k = 0;
for i in km.labels_ :
  clusters[i].append(dataset_files.filenames[k])  
  k += 1
```

and then i print it :)

```
for clust in clusters :
  print "\n************************\n"
  for filename in clusters[clust] :
    print filename
```

Comment: This helped me figure out how to display which observations belonged to each cluster for a non-file dataset. Thanks!