# How to apply nltk to categorize questions

Tags: python, nlp, data-mining, text-mining, text-classification

I have a list of questions in a text file extracted from online website. I am new to nltk (in Python) and going through initial chapters from ( http://http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516499.do ) . Please anybody help me out for categorizing my topics under different headings. 
I don't know the heading of the questions. So, how to create headings and categorize then thenafter ???

Answer (score 0):

Your task consists of [document clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_clustering), where each question is a document, and [cluster labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_labeling), where label designates topic.
Note that if your questions are short and/or hardly separable, e.g. belong to similar categories, then quality would be not so high.

Take a look at [simple recipe](http://bogdan-ivanov.com/recipe-text-clustering-using-nltk-and-scikit-learn/) for document clustering and related questions [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789254/clustering-text-in-python) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788431/scikit-learn-how-to-know-documents-in-the-cluster).

As a baseline for labels, try max tf-idf words from cluster words or from centroids.